# Cannot POST /admin Error return in web browser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, multer

I want to update my images on the blog page. but I got an error in the web browser like

```
Cannot POST /admin/portfolio/609911b1fba77be609396747/edit_cover
```

here is edit_cover.ejs file code and I use post method to submit images in the database

```
<%-include('./partials/header')%>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text text-primary">Change Porfolio Cover Image Section</h1>
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
            <form action="/admin/portfolio/<%=work._id%>/edit_cover" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Cover</label>
                    <input type="file" name="cover" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlFile2">Snaps of Project</label>
                    <input class="form-control-file" name="images" type="file" id="exampleFormControlFile2" multiple>
                  </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Update</button>
                </div>
                </form>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                
                    </div>
                    </div>

</div>
```

My router.js file code is here and two lines of code in here one is get request and other is for post

```
router.get('/admin/portfolio/:id/cover_edit',serverController.isAuthenticated,serverController.portfolio_edit_cover)
router.post('/admin/portfolio/:id/cover_edit',serverController.isAuthenticated,upload.fields([{name: "cover", maxCount: 1},{name: "images", maxCount: 12}]),serverController.portfolio_edit_cover_post)
```

here is my backend controller and code for images updating

```
exports.portfolio_edit_cover = async function(req,res){
    res.render('server/edit_cover',{
        work : await workCollection.findOne({_id: objectId(req.params.id)})
    })
}

exports.portfolio_edit_cover_post = function(req,res){
    let uploadImages = new Work(req.body, req.files, req.params.id)
    console.log(req.files)
    uploadImages.up().then((result)=>{
        res.redirect('/admin/portfolio',{
            work : result
        })
        
    }).catch(()=>{
        res.send('404')
    })
}
```

and lastly this all about my model  codes. in the following code is just for how update my data onto databae

```
Work.prototype.up = function(){
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
        await workCollection.updateOne({_id : objectId(this.id)}, {$set :
        
            {
                images : this.images
            }
        }
       
    )
    resolve()
    })
}

module.exports = Work
```

Answer (score 0):

in edit_cover.js file it has path like

`action="/admin/portfolio/<%=work._id%>**/edit_cover**"`  and router.js it's like

```
router.get('/admin/portfolio/:id**/cover_edit**',serverController.isAuthenticated,serverController.portfolio_edit_cover)
router.post('/admin/portfolio/:id**/cover_edit**',serverController.isAuthenticated,upload.fields([{name: "cover", maxCount: 1},{name: "images", maxCount: 12}]),serverController.portfolio_edit_cover_post)
```

both of these need to have the same path; everything is fine but at last segment, it should be `/cover_edit`